# I can't work locally unless connected to the internet - how to fix?

Tags: firefox, localhost

In Firefox, when I am disconnected from the net, I want to work locally on my local IIS server (Win XP, Firefox 3.5.10). I do NOT have Work Offline checked but FF says that it cannot find my site (ie. the message from FF if you try to access an online site offline) This applies to any localhost URL. I tried 127.0.0.1 and checked my Host file - that does not work either.

If I check Work Offline then it shows the Firefox message that it cannot be reached because I have Work Offline checked. Unchecking it does not help.

Then - I load up Safari, copy and paste the URL into that browser and it connects to my development localhost site. It is not just browser caching as I can log in, etc.

So Firefox will not let me develop locally unless I am connected to the internet, which is a problem. Suggestions please?

*Update* :

Thanks, but unfortunately that does not work. I installed it and the problem remains. IE and Safari work fine.

I also tried: `localhost:80`, pinging `localhost` (which replies with 127.0.0.1 as expected). I am not using a proxy and have checked all settings for any type of exception.

Comment: Please edit your question to list all the addons you have in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://yellosoft.us/index.php?id=88

This will disable offline mode for good, made exactly for the `localhost` needs.

For more information and ideas, here:
https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/11503

Comment: Strange that work offline kicks in for localhost, doesn't do that to me in Firefox.

Comment: Both links are donw.... and no other good answers on this question

Answer (score 0):

Working in "offline mode" means for a browser to work from it's cache, i.e. not on your local computer or network, as there is no difference on how much does a computer can see from the Internet: just your own computer or local network, or a half of it or the entire Internet.

You might want to try [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) plug-in for FireFox. It helps allot to solve problems.

So, if your browser is in "online mode" (and disconnected from the net) but can't even access "localhost" than there's something really messed up with your installation, so you need to reset the FF settings, as a new installation is quite probable to pick up the old settings left on your computer.

If however localhost is working this way, but other URLs don't (form IIS) than FireBug's Network tab might give you more details about what's going on there.